# WIX 3.5 Multiple Instances Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, installation, wix

I have a simple WIX installer which will install a Windows Service.  I have Multiple Instances setup so that the service can run side by side.

Everything is looking good the only problem I'm now having is when I uninstall the installation.  It completely removes the actual windows service executable, however it doesn't completely remove the registry entry.  Going into the `services.msc` I can still see the service name.  I have to go into the registry and manually delete the entry.

Check out my VS2010 solution here:  http://andrewherrick.com/spike/multiplewindowsservices.zip

You can easily recreate it by installing the default instance, then install instance 01 side by side.  Then try and uninstall instance 01.  You will see it isn't removed from the services list.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you installing the different instances to different directories?

Comment: correct using the INSTALLLOCATION parameter with MSIEXEC to set the install directory.  Two seperate directories where the Service EXEs are housed.

Comment: I know there are issues with component that have non-file keypaths when doing multiple instances ( they have to have unique GUIDs ) but I haven't seen this as a problem with FILE key paths.  Is it possible your testing machine was dirty and had incorrect reference counts?   Try a clean VM that is snapshotted.

Comment: Christopher thanks for the response.  I was actually able to get it working by upgrading to 3.6 and setting the MultiInstance attribute to Yes

Comment: Good to know.  I know how it works from an MSI perspective and how InstallShield does it. Take a look at this for fun: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/03/installshield-2009-beta-part-i.html

Comment: @aherrick, I think you should drop this question if you got it working yourself - it seems not to bring a value by itself in the current shape...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade to WIX 3.6 which allows MultiInstance installs at the component level.